# Ribarci border crossing

Tags: borders, bulgaria, serbia, scenic-routes

Is Ribarci border crossing from Serbia to Bulgaria open for foreign nationals (non Bulgarian or Serbian)?

I'm thinking of taking this road as it seems to be in the mountains so I hope to see some nice views along the way from Serbia to Bansko.
Can anyone confirm if this is the case? Does it worth the long drive instead of faster ways? (I'll be coming from Belgrade)

Comment: I am not going to write a proper answer, as I am not 100% sure, but it is not at all common that European border crossings are only open for certain nationalities. I would very much assume that you, no matter where you are from, can cross the border there.

Comment: There are many examples, Slovenia and Croatia come to mind, which have crossings only open to locals/EU citizens. However, Ribarci is listed as an international border crossing open around the clock and all I can find about restrictions is closures in 2020 for Covid.